# RoR help protecting my CRUD links in the views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, crud

I have four models:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postcards
end

class Postcard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :Country
  has_many :photos
  has_many :tips
end

class Photos < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postcard
end

class Tips < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :postcard
end
```

The routes are nested like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :countrys do
    resources :postcards do 
      resources :photos, :tips
    end
  end
end
```

I followed the CRUD architecture and everything is working fine, all the controllers are working. I used private / country_params for create and update controllers method. But....

Now I realise that if I deploy the app, anyone can click the links in views to create/edit/destroy the database.

What is the "good practice" solution to limit access?

1. building an user model just for me and take admin-right ?
2. Creating a new set of view without crud access ?(is that even possible?)
3. using admin gem (RailsAdmin or ActiveAdmin) ?

Comment: In the dangerous actions (C, U, D) you should check if this user is authorized to perform the action. Obviously, you want to restrict anonymous users. Take a look at cancancan gem, I used it successfully in many projects.

Comment: "a new set of view without crud access" - you realize that R in CRUD means "read"? :)

Comment: thx for the cancancan tips, does it work if i am the only one user (i didn't plan login capacity for the app) and can it hide the actual links in the views ?
- yea good one ... so Crud -r  ;)

Comment: if you are the only user, that makes it simple. Simply apply a before filter where you have to login to use create, edit and destroy actions.

Comment: haa ok googling it right now ! thx a lot

Comment: Do i still need the cancancan gem ? or just using a method .filter is enough ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit the content on your application to only be accessed by you, you must implement some simple authentication (who can see what) and authorization (what can they see).

Follow the steps in this tutorial to implement simple authentication with a User model.  When creating this User model you will want to add a `role` field.

https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014

This role field should be validated such that it can only be a role from some array of your role types.  Include this array of roles in the User model and validate that the role of the User is in this array.

```
ROLES = [['Admin', :admin], ['Guest',:guest]]  
validates :role, inclusion: { in: %w[admin guest] }
```

Once you have this authentication in place (with login/sign up views), you can work on implementing authorization.  To do this use the **cancancan** gem.

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

You only want to give access to "admin" users, so you can define the "abilities" of each user role type using this gem.  For example:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all  # can do any action on all objects
    else
      can :read, :all  # can only read things but can't edit them
    end
  end
end
```

This would give admin users rights to do anything in the app, but guest users could only read information.  See the cancancan docs for more ways to define abilities.

Now, because you have set the abilities for the different roles, in your controller you can limit access to certain functionality.  You can also limit what the users sees.

```
<% if can? :update, @item %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>

<% end %>
```

This code will only show the "Edit" button if the user is allowed to edit an item based on the abilities that you have defined.

Comment: Remember to also use the `load_and_authorize_resource` method in your controllers to authorize controller methods.  See [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#2-check-abilities--authorization)